# Spring RequestScope service in Singleton Filter error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a microservice which receive the user info as request header.
I would like to save the user info in a RequestScoped bean in order to be sure that the user is set for each request.
there fore I wrote this Filter:

```
@Component
public class UserSetFilter implements Filter {

 private final UserService userService;

 public UserSetFilter(UserService userService) {
     this.userService = userService;
 }

 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final var user = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getHeader("user");
    userService.setUser(user);

    chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
 }
}
```

And this is my service

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserService {
  private String user;

  public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public String getUser() {
     return user;
  }
}
```

As soon as my service is called there is an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

How can I solve this? if this is not the way, how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from `RequestScope`? Are you registering your `UserSetFilter` into spring?

Comment: I guess you might want to look for `Proxy-Mode`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13227931/2039546

Comment: @Ashutosh
From my understanding  `RequestScope is a composed annotation for @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` as you can see here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Comment: @ismlydz I used RequestScope which should set the scope as Request and the proxy mode as TARGET_CLASS. However I tried to replace Request scope with `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this
UserService userService = (UserService) servletRequest.getAttribute("scopedTarget.userService");